# Is it possible to identify a bluetooth device that has not be made discoverable?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth dongle that I have plugged into a usb power port, through which there is no data transfer.

I want my android device to recognise when it is in the proximity of this dongle, and for an event to fire when it is no longer in the proximity of the dongle.

As there is no data transfer through the usb port, I can't make the dongle discoverable. I don't need to communicate with it though, I only want to see that it's there or that I have lost the connection with it.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: its almost like the answer is in the question, i am going to follow this! for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of the manufacturer of the Bluetooth device . Some devices allow Bluetooth to be on when the device is not discoverable.

If you know the MAC Address of your bluetooth device you can directly connect to it even when the device is not discoverable.

Android will let you do this with [createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29)

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = adapter.getRemoteDevice("00:00:00:00:00:00");
BluetoothSockt socket = remoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);
socket.connect();
```

Comment: By the looks of this, I still need to make the device discoverable - at least the first time - to get the MAC address.

Comment: And you cannot get the mac address or your device before to plug it in the usb port and for the rest of life you should be able to use it without to make the device discoverable? You want to connect to a bluetooth device without to never never make the device discoverable?